# Can I see how long I've been working on an Xcode Project?

Tags: xcode

Title says it all...

On microsoft word theres a "total editing time" counter that tells you how long you've been working on your word document. Is there a similar feature in Xcode 7.3 in which I can see how long I've been working on my project? I'd like the time in hours.

EDIT: Based on answers I'm seeing there's 3rd party software to track my activity, can any of these work retroactively? I.E. Can I retrieve my hours from the past

-Maybe perhaps I can calculate time based on some logged builds? Or error log messages or something that's deep in my workspace? Any Ideas on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO. There is no way to check such counter in Xcode. However you can use [RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/dashboard) to detect accurate time on Xcode or any other software.

RescueTime helps you understand your daily habits so you can focus and be more productive.

You can also use [xcode-wakatime](https://github.com/wakatime/xcode-wakatime) or any other third party.

I personally use [RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/dashboard). It is best, manages lots of more than Xcode.

Comment: Can I get previous work time? Before the installation?

Comment: No, You have to install either plug-in, or rescue time. else you have to trust one who was working on system :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [xcode-wakatime](https://github.com/wakatime/xcode-wakatime). Honestly I have never used it so I cannot write personal feedbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you actually can. But you need to integrate [WakaTime](https://wakatime.com) plugin for `Xcode`.
Here is a [setup](https://wakatime.com/xcode) documentation.